# Oozie let other forked actions continue in case one fails but terminate after the join

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I have a work-flow that I fork into 3 actions.

```
<start to="PARALLEL_PROCESS_FORK"/>
<fork name="MY_FORK">
<path start="START_PARALLEL_PATH_1"/>
<path start="START_PARALLEL_PATH_2"/>
<path start="START_PARALLEL_PATH_3"/>
</fork>
```

The three paths start a series of actions, each of which can fail.
What I find trivial to do is to create the following DAG. After the `join`other actions follow. The proble with the DAG below is that, if I reach a `kill` node, for example at the top path, all other path will be also killed before reaching the `join`.

[image: Current execution]

However, this is not the desired flow. What I need is that, if an action at a parallel path fails, I need to kill only that path of execution but the other paths should continue until the join. For example, if action `A2` fails, action `A3` will be skipped, but `C1`, `C2`, `C3` will be executed. The decision node after the `join` will detect that an error happened and will terminate.

[image: Desired solution]

Do you know how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Using wf:actionExternalStatus**

In this case, the idea is simple: use the external status of a node to determine what to do next.

[image]

The status of a node can be either RUNNING, KILLED, FAILED, SUCCEEDED, empty if the node has been skipped, or "FAILED/KILLED". So we need to check for the KILLED or FAILED statuses. Given the limitations of the default [Oozie EL functions](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions), we can use the following construct:

```xml
<decision name="check-if-action-failed">
  <switch>
    <case to="kill_A">
      ${replaceAll(wf:actionExternalStatus('A1'), '.*FAILED.*|.*KILLED.*', 'FAILED') eq 'FAILED'} or
      ${replaceAll(wf:actionExternalStatus('A3'), '.*FAILED.*|.*KILLED.*', 'FAILED') eq 'FAILED'}
    </case>
    <case to="kill_C">
      ${replaceAll(wf:actionExternalStatus('C1'), '.*FAILED.*|.*KILLED.*', 'FAILED') eq 'FAILED'} or
      ${replaceAll(wf:actionExternalStatus('C2'), '.*FAILED.*|.*KILLED.*', 'FAILED') eq 'FAILED'}
    </case>
    <default to="next-action"/>
  </switch>
</decision>
```

**Option 2: Using a shell-script**

The workaround that I show below is to use a Shell script in the nodes that are `KO`. These are the nodes where we want the parallel branch to step execution, but let the other parallel branches reach the join.
[image]

So in the image above we have `KO_A` and `KO_C`. This will invoke a shell script `echo-ko.sh`that will simply do:

```bash
echo "STATUS=KO"
```

In Oozie terms these nodes will look like:

*KO_A*

```xml
<action name="KO_A" retry-max="3" retry-interval="2">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.3">
        <exec>echo-ko.sh</exec>
        <file>\path\to\script\echo-ko.sh</file>
        <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="my-join"/>
    <error to="some-fail-node"/>
</action>
```

*Decision after the join*

```xml
<decision name="check-branch-ko">
    <switch>
        <case to="kill_A">
            ${wf:actionData('KO_A')['STATUS'] eq 'KO'}
        </case>
        <!-- Other cases --> 
        <default to="..."/>
    </switch>
</decision>
```